# Unexpected token 'const' | Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my bot online but this error came up:

```
C:\Users\My\Path\To\Success\Visual Studio code\Discord Bots\Testing\First Try\Intents\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:18
const WebSocket = (function findWebSocket() {
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
```

I went to the error but I was unsure on what to change. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of nodejs?  What code is immediately before this?  This actually looks like one of those kind of errors you get when the code before this has some sort of error in it and this token is unexepected because of what comes before.  Or it could be an old version of nodejs that doesn't yet support `const`.

Comment: And please indicate a version of Discord.js

Comment: I'm using discord v11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need both `const` and a named function. Try one of these:

```
const findWebSocket = function() {
  ...
}

// OR

function findWebSocket() {
  ...
}
```

On an additional note, its kind of an anti practice to name a function with a capital first letter in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

U don't need to name the function twice.
 `const WebSocket = function()`
or
just the function without the const its will look like that `function WebSocket()`
You can use arrow function as well,  `const WebSocket= () =>{ }`